# Fragment$Companion cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment on BottomNavigationView listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, androidx, fragmentmanager

My bottom navigation view should work with tabs, but in some way I cannot cast

> fragment as Fragment

anymore with AndroidX

There is crash every time when I click on menu item

```java
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.spacexmonitor.MissionListFragment$Companion cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
            at com.spacexmonitor.MainActivity$onCreate$menuOnNavigationItemSelectedListener$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:28)
```

There is my Activity:

```java
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, MissionListFragment())
                fragmentTransaction.commit()
            }

            val menuOnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
                bottomNavigationBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
                    when (item.itemId) {
                        R.id.launchesMenuItem -> {
                            val fragment = MissionListFragment
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment as Fragment)
                                .commit()

                            return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                        }
                        R.id.chartsMenuItem -> {
                            val fragment = MissionChartFragment
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment as Fragment)
                                .commit()

                            return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                        }
                    }
                    false
                }
        }
    }
```

My empty fragment:

```java
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

class MissionChartFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        private val MISSION_CHART = "mission chart"
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mission_chart, container, false)
    }
}
```

A lot of answers here is to change `app.Fragment` to `v4.Fragment` usage, but this solution is not helping with my issue.

Comment: Since you are working with androidx libraries, your Fragment has to extend `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

Comment: It is extending `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` in both fragments

Comment: Post MissionListFragment class

Comment: Posted MissionChartFragment to simplify reading

Comment: why are you using the cast `fragment as Fragment`? It should just be a `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

Comment: in case if Im using simple call `fragment` is says `Required Fragment found MissionChartFragment.Companion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
val fragment = MissionListFragment
```

to

```
val fragment = MissionListFragment()
```

Using `fragment = MissionListFragment` you are linking the `companion object` of the `MissionChartFragment`

Comment: Works like a charm, missed constructor was the problem, gratz